# Custom unmarshaling a struct into a map of slices

Tags: json, dictionary, go, unmarshalling

I thought I understood unmarshalling by now, but I guess not. I'm having a little bit of trouble unmarshalling a map in go. Here is the code that I have so far

```
type OHLC_RESS struct {
    Pair map[string][]Candles
    Last int64 `json:"last"`
}

type Candles struct {
    Time   uint64
    Open   string
    High   string
    Low    string
    Close  string
    VWAP   string
    Volume string
    Count  int
}

func (c *Candles) UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    tmp := []interface{}{&c.Time, &c.Open, &c.High, &c.Low, &c.Close, &c.VWAP, &c.Volume, &c.Count}
    length := len(tmp)
    err := json.Unmarshal(d, &tmp)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    g := len(tmp)
    if g != length {
        return fmt.Errorf("Lengths don't match: %d != %d", g, length)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    response := []byte(`{"XXBTZUSD":[[1616662740,"52591.9","52599.9","52591.8","52599.9","52599.1","0.11091626",5],[1616662740,"52591.9","52599.9","52591.8","52599.9","52599.1","0.11091626",5]],"last":15}`)
    var resp OHLC_RESS
    err := json.Unmarshal(response, &resp)
    fmt.Println("resp: ", resp)
}
```

after running the code, the `last` field will unmarshal fine, but for whatever reason, the map is left without any value. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expedient solution, for the specific example JSON, would be to NOT use a map at all but instead change the structure of `OHLC_RESS` so that it matches the structure of the JSON, i.e.

```golang
type OHLC_RESS struct {
    Pair []Candles `json:"XXBTZUSD"`
    Last int64     `json:"last"`
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Z9PhJt3wX33

---

However it's safe to assume, I think, that the reason you've opted to use a map is because the JSON object's key(s) that hold the "pairs" can vary and so hardcoding them into the field's tag is out of the question.

To understand why your code doesn't produce the desired result, you have to realize two things. First, the *order* of a struct's fields has *no bearing* on how the keys of a JSON object will be decoded. Second, the name `Pair` holds *no special meaning* for the unmarshaler. Therefore, by default, the unmarshaler has *no way* of knowing that your wish is to decode the `"XXBTZUSD": [ ... ]` element into the `Pair` map.

So, to get your desired result, you can have the `OHLC_RESS` implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface and do the following:

```golang
func (r *OHLC_RESS) UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    // first, decode just the object's keys and leave
    // the values as raw, non-decoded JSON
    var obj map[string]json.RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal(d, &obj); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // next, look up the "last" element's raw, non-decoded value
    // and, if it is present, then decode it into the Last field
    if last, ok := obj["last"]; ok {
        if err := json.Unmarshal(last, &r.Last); err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // remove the element so it's not in
        // the way when decoding the rest below
        delete(obj, "last")
    }

    // finally, decode the rest of the element values
    // in the object and store them in the Pair field
    r.Pair = make(map[string][]Candles, len(obj))
    for key, val := range obj {
        cc := []Candles{}
        if err := json.Unmarshal(val, &cc); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        r.Pair[key] = cc
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Lj8a8Gx9fWH

Comment: Would you please explain what you did?

Comment: thanks so much! never realized a map would need an unmarshaljson func as well. should've known, since it's go, after all

Comment: @Avinash I've now updated the code in the answer with some comments. I hope they help clarify what the code is doing.

Comment: @mkopriva, Thanks it helps. Actually I was not aware that we could write custom `UnmarshalJSON` before. Its a nice thing to learn.

Comment: @Avinash yes, if the `encoding/json` unmarshaler encounters a type that implements the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.18.2#Unmarshaler) interface, it will invoke the `UnmarshalJSON` method instead of performing the default unmarshaling. And there's also the [`json.Marshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.18.2#Marshaler) interface that can also be implemented to customize the marshaling process.