# Cannot unmarshal array of lists where elements don't have the same type

Tags: json, go, binance

I'm scraping Binance API for candle price data. The Binance API provides the said data as json array. Each element of the array is a list representing candle and does not contain elements of the same type, however each list contains the same set of types: strings and ints, to be precise. Look at the raw data of this for instance: https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=ZECUSDT&interval=1h&limit=10&startTime=1653001200000

How do I automatically unmarshal such json into struct? Is using reflect the only option here?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

type PriceData struct {
    Data map[int]Price
}

type Price struct {
    TradeStart uint64 `json:"0"` // tried without json tags
    PriceOpen  string `json:"1"` 
    PriceHigh  string `json:"2"`
    PriceLow   string `json:"3"`
    PriceClose string `json:"4"`    
    TradeEnd   uint64 `json:"6"`
    // QuoteVolume         string // tried with these fields as well
    // NumberOfTrades      uint64
    // TakerBuyBaseVolume  string
    // TakerBuyQuoteVolume string
}

func main() {
    url := "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=ZECUSDT&interval=1h&limit=10&startTime=1653001200000" // tried /api/v1 as well

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // var priceData map[int]Price // -- tried
    // var priceData []Price // -- tried
    // var priceData PriceData // -- tried
    // var priceData []interface{} -- works fine, but will need to use reflection
    var priceData []Price
    if err = json.Unmarshal(content, &priceData); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    interupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(interupt, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGINT)
    <-interupt
}
```

Comment: This recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72313698/custom-unmarshaling-a-struct-into-a-map-of-slices) is also about candles, not sure if they are binance or not, though.

Comment: @mkopriva I've seen it. Unfortunately, it's no about Binance and elements of list contained in array are all of the same type there.

Comment: I see it now, but if you look at the `(*Candle) UnmarshalJSON` code in the question, (not the answer), then that is a valid approach to decode the binance array of arrays into a Go slice of structs. Just implement the `UnmarshalJSON` on your `*Price` type and make sure the order of the fields passed to the `[]interface{}` argument is correct and you should be good to go.